# MYOB Service Sales Import

Tags: csv, import, myob

I have developed an export file from our Job Management system that I want to be able to import into MYOB Accounting Plus v18.5.

The file is generated without issue and I have included every single field to make it easy for upload (i.e. Match All matches every field)

The problem I am having is no matter what I do, I cannot get the sales to import... Every time, no matter what I do or how I create the customer card comes back with:

Error -190:  Customer not found. Sale invoice not imported.

I have tried matching using - co./Last Name, Card ID & Record ID and every time I get the same error.

I have created a single customer with a simply Co./Last Name, Card ID & Record ID and still, when I try to import using these same fields exactly matched, I get the same error...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Just leave the Card ID and Record ID blank and make sure you use "Identify Customer by: Co./Last Name" and the Alphanumeric matches.